# css hover come back transition

Tags: html, css

i have this code and the image goes up with with the transition but I would like to came back with the transition down when my mouse goes somewhere else
my actually code;

```
 .yt:hover  {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
    transition-duration: 2s;
  }
```

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example to your question, see [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for how to do this - we can't tell from the small bit of CSS you have shown how you have set up .yt for example so any answer would just be a guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
.yt {
  transition: 2s;
}

.yt:hover  {
  transform: translateY(-30px);
}
```

Move the transition attribute to the whole object

Answer (score 0):

```css
img{
transition: all 2s;
}
img:hover {
  transform: translateY(-30px);
}
```

```html
<img src="some_src.jpg" />
```